# Tool to help the Helpdesk

Tags: windows, web-apps, powershell

I'm searching for a tool, OpenSource would be awesome but in the end we would also pay, to help our Helpdesk. What I have in mind is something like a WebApp to start predefined scripts for stuff like Password Reset, add Users to a group, stuff like that.

We found a tool called ScriptRunner which looks promising, but are there alternatives?
Thanks!

Comment: So to clarify, you want a solution to automate tasks that your Helpdesk staff perform frequently?

Comment: Yeah, but also something like a dashboard our Helpdesk could run scripts to reset Active Directory passwords for a given user.